# PHP Prevent 'Like' Button Spam

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, button, spam

I am trying to create a like button next to a user comment the problem is a malicious user could spam the button and it would query the database many time for validity, this is a problem.
I thought about implementing a time-stamp check using CodeIgniter's Sessions but it is not working correctly. Example:

```
if ($this->session->userdata('last_activity') + 30 < time())
            echo 'ok';
        else
            echo 'NOT ok';
```

The 'like' button uses AJAX, any ideas on how to prevent spam on the server side?

Comment: what not working? what's happening?

Comment: @user790454 It says 'NOT okay' most of the time.

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath There is nothing wrong with the code itself but the logic. Can you provide a way for preventing spam from a button?

Comment: You can do it with JQuery / Javascript but they can still modify that. Check this out : http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Preventing-Multiple-Submits.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try this alternative solution i.e., you can create a link as "LIKE" and "UNLIKE". When the user clicks on "LIKE" update the status (lets say to 1) to that particular post or comment and while displaying check for the logic that if status == 1 it should show the "UNLIKE" OR else "LIKE" link . And when the user clicks on "UNLIKE" update the status (lets say to 0) for the same. So, from this can provide spam clicks and will only show one link at a time.

Comment: The "Upvote" button on SO works this way. Now, how do you identify that all the "likes" come from the same entity? IP Address? CSRF token? Both are easily worked around.

Comment: You can also fetch and update the ipaddress from which the "likes" come from and according check your conditions for the same.

Comment: @Rushikesh That is exactly how I implemented it the problem is that I am trying to prevent unnecessary queries to the database that is the whole point of my question.

Comment: What you can do is when the user clicks on "like" store the ip address of that as well when you change the status for like, and while displaying you can check whether the stored ip address and the pc's ip address, if they are same do not show "like" link or some other condition which you want to check..